# Refresh datagridview in Parent Form from Child Form?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

We have a Form called `FormParent` with a `datagridview`. Each cell in the `datagridview` is an instance of `UserControl`. There's a method in `FormParent` that looks like this:

```
private void RefreshParentFormDatagridview()
{
    DataTable myTable = GetEmployees();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = DT;
}
```

When I click on a cell of `datagridview`, I'm actually clicking on an instance of `UserControl`. This click opens a Form called `FormChild`

The `UserControl` click looks like this:

```
private void UserControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var formChild = new FormChild();
    formChild.ShowDialog();
}
```

`FormChild` has a button that does *stuff* to update some data; in this button_Click event handler I also want refresh (ie. rebind) the `datagridview` from `FormParent`. How can I do this? It's something like this:

```
private void buttonChildForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /* Saving stuff to database table */

    MessageBox.Show("Stuff saved");
    this.buttonSave.Enabled = false;

    /* run datagridview.datasource to update datagridview in FormParent */
}
```

How can I invoke `RefreshParentFormDatagridview` in `FormParent` from `buttonChildForm_Click` so that the `datagridview` is refreshed?

Thanks.

Comment: You can raise an event in user control and subscribe for it in main form and load data there. Also you can carry a reference of the form to the user control and then to your child form and call the method of load data there. It depends to implementation details of user control and how you show it in cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up passing a reference to dataGridView1 control to my UC, which then passed it to the child form.

Used this as reference: [how to refresh grid on parent form from child form](http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-refresh-grid-on-parent-form-from-child-form)